# Single table vs multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I have different clients with their information. All the clients have the same information. One client is one table and each one have the same columns as other client.

My question is, What is more efficient or what is better or which is the best way to do this?

- Only one table with all the clients information (with a new column distinguishing the different clients)
- One table for each client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use one table with all the client's information. Something that could be of much use to you would be this site: [SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp) Not only does it have explanations for the main programming of the SQL language, but the tutorial examples are a lot like what you are utilizing. When you use one table for each client, it gets extremely messy if you have more than 5, and it is tedious for your server to be working that hard. Good Luck!

Comment: Ok! I will try with one table so. :) Thank you for the site it seems interesting!